# ItemSource Binding in WPF grid that contains multiple columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am learning WPF following the MVVM pattern, I have come across an issue in XAML where I am binding the ItemSource for a grid I have. Currently I am binding each column to a Public Property that exists in my Model which works fine.

The issue I am having is that I do not know what to bind the Grids ItemSource too, as previously I have bound this to a Property, but when doing this is will only display the data for that one Property, is there a way I can bind this so I can display data for both columns.
Thanks,

MainWindow.Xaml

```
    <ListView Name="UserGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,178,12,13"  ItemsSource="{Binding ClientRatesPreAwr}"  >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                <GridViewColumn Header="PreAWR" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientRatesPreAwr}"  Width="50"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="PostAWR" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientRatesPostAwr}"  Width="50"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Model:

```
public string ClientRatesPreAwr
    {
        get { return _ClientRatePreAWR; }
        set
        {
            _ClientRatePreAWR = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPreAWR");
        }
    }

    public string ClientRatesPostAwr
    {
        get { return _ClientRatePostAWR; }
        set
        {
            _ClientRatePostAWR = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPostAwr");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The ItemsSource should be bound to a collection of Model objects, preferrably an `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

The ListView ItemSource should be bound to a collection of (ClientRates?) items in your model / view model, rather than an individual property.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind ListView to an `ObservableCollection<T>` like following example

```
<ListView Name="Items" ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="First name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Last name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

private ObservableCollection<Contact> items;
public ObservableCollection<Contact> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set
    {
        if (value != items)
        {
            items = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover I suggest to use Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework. It is easy to use and comfortable. Here is [a basic example](http://hintdesk.com/c-wpf-mvvm-databinding-2014/) for applying Caliburn.Micro